# Detect time of last change on a Microsoft Access database table

Tags: ms-access, oledb, ado

Does anyone know of a way to detect when the last time a Microsoft Access table has been changed (inserted into or updated)?  We used OLEDB via ADO COM to communicate with an access database programmatically and were looking for a way of detecting changes to specific tables.  We don't need to know what those changes are, just that changes were made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to detect if data in the table has changed is to perform a query against the table.

You must add a column of type `DATETIME` to the table e.g. named `LastUpdatedDate` that indicates the last updated date/time of each row. Make it `NOT NULL` so that you will have to write an updated `DATETIME` value to that column for each `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. Also, set the column to have a default of `DATE()` for the current date stamp or `NOW()` for the current date/time stamp. Then add a Validation Rule or `CHECK` constraint  e.g. `CHECK (LastUpdatedDate = NOW())` to ensure the column is actually updated on each `UPDATE` and `INSERT`.

Finally, run a `MAX(LastUpdatedDate)` query and you will get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way without "manually" writing to a column each time you access the table.

Answer (score 0):

As others have indicated there is no way to track changes without coding it yourself.

There's a simple example at 
ACC2000: How to Create an Audit Trail of Record Changes in a Form
    http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q197592

Audit Trail - Log changes at the record level at:
http://allenbrowne.com/AppAudit.html
The article addresses edits, inserts, and deletes for a form and subform.

Modules: Maintain a history of changes
http://www.mvps.org/access/modules/mdl0021.htm
The History Table routine is designed to write history records that track the changes made to fields in one or more tables.

Comment: I don't think any of these will work if they are using OLEDB via ADO COM to communicate with an access database programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement a timestamp column in your table, and update the value during your data changes.